# Command-line util to batch resize PDF files

Tags: gratis, pdf

Is there any tool to batch resize (change dpi, e.g. from 600 dpi to 300 dpi) large amount (100,000+) PDF files? Preferably for Windows command line.

I have no budget, so the tool must come free of charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use [imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) to [change your PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605006/convert-pdf-to-image-with-high-resolution).

Combined with a simple [for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/iterate-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-for-loop) (or something more advanced like [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)), you can cook up something like this:

```
for %f in (originals\*) do convert %f -density 300 resized\%f
```

Note that if you put that into a batch file, you need to escape the percent signs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PDFTK-Server](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) and using the command below to compress the files you need.

```
convert input.pdf -compress Zip output.pdf
```

Here you can find the whole manual https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you of two ways of doing that...

1. (*simpler one BUT not viable when you have a lot of PDFs*) use online tools to do that; for example: 
   http://www.ilovepdf.com/compress_pdf or https://www.pdfcompress.com/
   (just a couple of links, you can just google for "online pdf compressor" and you'll find a lot)
2. use [ghostscript](http://ghostscript.com/);
   **this is the way you'll have to follow when you have to deal with a lot of PDFs file**. As already mentioned by Frederick Nord in his answer you need to put it in a ***for-loop*** within your batch file (using ghostscript instead of imagemagick in this case), so here's an example command:

   ```
   for %f in (originals\*) do gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=resized\%f %f
   ```

Here's a [reference link](http://www.tjansson.dk/2012/04/compressing-pdfs-using-ghostscript-under-linux/) for the ***gs*** command you may find interesting and here's [official documentation](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm).

Finally, you'll surely appreciate even Kurt Pfeifle great answers on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10453202/1078556) and [here on SoftwareRecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/18459/15456).

Comment: P.S. [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) can make use of ghostscript too (see [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-ways-reduce-size-pdf-file/)), so you may want to give it try to do the batch file manipulation in a graphical way (some usage examples [here](http://www.ofzenandcomputing.com/batch-resize-images-irfanview/) and [here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/50519/simple-batch-conversion-using-irfanview/)).

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the answer of **danicotra**, in respect of the first solution, Ilovepdf, I can tell you right now that you can use a programmer-friendly API to process your PDF files in batches.

[Ilovepdf API](https://developer.ilovepdf.com/)

**Disclaimer:** I am the main developer of the Ruby's Ilovepdf repository.

PS: I would insert a comment directly in **danicotra**'s message but my Stackoverflow reputation does not suffice to do such action.